# Facet over a field in haystack for which stored=False in schema

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

Is it somehow possible to facet over a field in haystack for which stored=False in solr schema?

When I try to use the facet command, I get "Query failed" error.

I don't have permission to modify the schema. Have to do with what is given.

Comment: facet=true is required at query time, not on any field in schema. Did you mean `indexed=false`?

Comment: Sorry about the wrong info. I have edited the ques.

Comment: u can facet on field which has stored=false

Comment: what is the error that you get? What is the query that you are firing? Your question is having very little information to understand the problem